# How to format time-type data with mongodb and cubejs?

Tags: sql, cube.js

I found this url about this topic:

- https://cube.dev/docs/types-and-formats#dimensions-formats
- https://cube.dev/docs/working-with-string-time-dimensions

I didnt found the format for time-type.
So I try to use sql: `PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d', date)`

```
    createdat: {
      sql: `PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d',${CUBE}.\`createdAt\`)`,
      type: `time`
    },
```

it will return a error:

```
Error: Error: scalar function 'parse_timestamp' is not supported
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
createdat: {
    sql: `DATE(${CUBE}.\`createdAt\`, '%Y-%m-%d')`,
    type: `time`
},
```

Thanks

Comment: In the sql property, we use functions specific to the database we connected cube.js to. the example in the Docs they are using BigQuery.